# Legendary Character, the True Story

Tags: story-identification, books

I read a book probably no later than 2011, a full standalone novel, YA-focused, where the main character and some friends are defending their medieval fantasy country from a Romanesque invasion. The invaders ("Romans") build roads and aqueducts and so forth everywhere they conquer, but if they are unable to conquer a country in a year they will instead make alliances and continue conquest elsewhere, as a result of a devastating civil war when "Rome" was founded.

What really stood out to me was that each chapter was introduced by a few lines of either prophecy or legend describing in advance how the challenge would be overcome, but it was never quite right, as with a deceptive soothsayer or an intentional poetic retelling of events.

Other details include: some sort of earth/elemental magic taught by a nomadic desert tribe to the main characters. And the father of one of the characters was either the emperor or the general of the army who was shot as a way to refuse his offer of single combat to the "Romans." At some point a character uses natural magic to call down lightning in his/her own single combat with a "Roman" general.

I've tried various combinations of key terms from above, here and on Google, but am unable to find it. Any ideas?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Do you recall the cover art, or the names of any characters or places?  Was this a physical book or an e-book?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't remember either. It was definitely a physical book, checked out from a library. I would hazard a guess that places it much earlier than 2011, based only on "a library having it."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Farsala trilogy by Hilari Bell. Fall Of A Kingdom, Rise Of A Hero, and Forging The Sword.

From [a Goodreads review](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/248380.Fall_of_a_Kingdom):

> Throw in an enemy empire with a relatively liberal system of laws and *a tradition of either conquering a country within a year or giving up*—which sounds like an easy foe to beat until you realize how seldom they have given up—and you might begin to see why Farsala is poised, tipping, ready to fall.

and [Wikipedia plot summary](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farsala_Trilogy):

> When the first battle occurs, Jiann is chosen to carry the banner behind the commander, a very honorable position. However, during the battle, he tries to help his father, the commander, fight, but ends up being knocked to the ground and nearly trampled. He watches as the commander, to end the battle, decides to fight against one other warrior in a duel to see who will win the battle. If the commander won the duel, his own army would win the battle. If his opponent won, then their side would win. Instead, the Hrum send a barrage of arrows towards the commander, and kill him that way instead. Jiann is overcome with grief at his father's death, and takes command of the army.

Comment: Apologies I forgot to come back and accept until now, but this is definitely it! The "Legend of Sorahb" part of the wiki entry is precisely my second paragraph, and I recognize other bits of detail from the rest of it. Thank you!

I like the very last line of the wiki entry: "The Hrum seem to be loosely based on the Roman empire."